# How do I read in file and modify a file at the same time?

Tags: c#, file

I want to program in c#, read a file like this:

...

cindy cindy0 cindy1 cindy2 cindy3

miao miao0 miao1 miao2 miao3

...

And I want to add something like "cindy4" and the end of the first line.

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
string line = file.ReadLine();
while(line != null)
{
    if (line.Contains("cindy"))
    {
         tmp = line.Split(' ');
         file.Close();

         //TO DO change in the file

         break;
     }
     line = file.ReadLine();
}
```

In the TODO part, I code like this:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(System.IO.File.Open(filename, System.IO.FileMode.Open));
writer.Write("cindy4");
writer.Flush();
```

But it does not work. Could somebody get me an example?

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Error? Unexpected/wrong behavior?

Comment: For a task like this all the contents have to be read and re-written (there are some clever sliding window approaches to use constant memory, but might as well just read everything in *first* and then write it out because it's non-complicated and works well for trivial cases like this). There is no "insert" file operation.

Comment: @Krumia I do not see that it write "cindy4" in my file.

Comment: Your StreamReader probably has a lock on the file. Sure you are not getting an error?

Comment: @gunr2171 I got no error but it does not write anything in my file too. If it did, I wonder it will be in the right position or not. So I propose the question here.

Comment: @user2864740 I do not very understand your comment. Could you get me some example of using "insert" please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
string[] new_text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("file_path");
new_text[line_number] += "text_to_add"; 
//the line number start from zero 
//Example: first line will be: new_text[0]
//the second line will be: new_text[1]
//Etc...
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("file_path",new_text);
```